# org-mode and populating tables

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

How can I populate rows in a column with items from the todo lists based on custom sequences?

AKA:

```
* TODO <<something1>>
* WAITING <<something2>>
* BLOCKED <<something3>>
* TODO <<something4>>
```

And then a table that I can update using `C-c C-c` (using something like # TBLFM I'm guessing? ) based on items I add.

```
| TODO           | WAITING        | BLOCKED       |
| [[something1]] | [[something2]] | [[something3]]|
| [[something4]] |                |               |
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for kanban: http://draketo.de/light/english/free-software/el-kanban-org-table

Comment: Thats what I was attempting to use but the tables never update (even using his example code and game repo)